# Using awk to reformat table

Tags: bash, awk

I have this table,

```
ID ref1 ref2
a   1   3
b   3   1
c   5   1
d   2   4
```

Tab seperated and there are n number of IDs (a,b,c,..) and references (ref1,ref2,... and so on). I want to replace the numbers with its corresponding ID if greater than 2, so the desired output will be like,

```
ref1 ref2
b     a
c     d
```

I have manged to do for single columns with awk

```
awk -F "\t" '{if($2>2) print $1}' filename
```

and

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}$2>2{$2=$1}{print}' filename
```

But I can't use them for larger files.

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you.

Vivek

Comment: Id is always column 1?

Comment: But you need to tweak your required output to match your condition, you won't get the output as shown in your requirement for this

Comment: the final output is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Good attempt!*

You just need to loop through all the columns in `Awk` from `$2` to `NF` i.e. the last field and do the replacement,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i>2) $i=$1}1' file
```

`NR>1` should skip header line from processing and keep it as such. The `{}1` construct is equivalent to an *always true* condition for printing the lines, instead of using `{print}` within the clause in which case you are limiting the printing to conditions defined only within `{..}`

---

As needed by OP in comments, if `"NIL"` should be updated for the non-matching entries, fix it by

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i>2) { $i=$1 } else { $i="NIL" } }1'
```

Comment: Why are you using sub?

Comment: @123: Am sure `sub` (or) `gsub()` don't matter much here, because it is anyway going to be a single match. Unless you have anything against it

Comment: But you can just assign it the value directly, no need to call any function.

Comment: @123: Ahh, you meant that! probably lost it in the stream of thoughts, updated. Thanks!

Comment: Much appreciated Inian, it worked perfectly. And thank you for the description. If I want to add an else condition where all false value to be "NIL". What changes should I give?

Comment: Done. Thank you.